# User switching broken in 14.04

Tags: lightdm, gdm, switch-user

I just upgraded to 14.04.  I have an nVidia graphics card and am using the nVidia driver (proprietary, tested).  I am using gdm as I don't light the look of lightdm (also, I have two monitors and it doesn't seem to work well with that set up).  After the first user logs in the unity desktop seems to work fine.  However, selecting using the icon in the far upper right of the screen to select another user to switch to does absolutely nothing.  This seems, the screen doesn't go black, no authentication window pops up.  Nothing at all happens.  Only one user can be logged in at a time using the display manager.  I have read about a host of seemingly related problems.  However, I haven't been able to understand how to get basic user switching working.  Seems like a strange problem for a linux system to have.  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Purge lightdm via `sudo apt-get install purge lightdm` and check again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some bizare XDM behaviour.  Try logging out of your x session.  It should take you back to the DM.  Otherwise, as was suggested by A.B. remove any/all dm's you have (you may want to install something basic like xdm as a place holder while you remove what you really want).  As discussed purge rather than remove (removes config's as well as packages) then install again from fresh.  Personally, I'd try this:-

```
sudo apt-get install xdm
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get purge gdm
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo apt-get purge xdm
```

I believe the core approach to XDMs is using /etc/X11/default-display-manager.  Check the contents of that file, contains the full path to your chosen DM.

That said, I personally use kdm and kde, so this is what happens on my pc:-

```
# cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/bin/kdm
```